# Getting 2 floating divs to cover the whole width of page with border

Tags: css, html

I know usually  setting widths 50% works, but I need to have a border in the middle, and this causes the divs to add up to more than the width of the whole page. Are there any CSS3 tricks to fix this?

THanks

Comment: Why are they floating divs?  What is the purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the box-sizing to border-box:

```
div
{
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `overflow: hidden` on parent div to clip any exceeding space.

You can also use `z-index` to place the 50% div with border on a 100% div.

[z-index info](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3JkGk/3/

Comment: that's not what I'm looking for tho, I need them to be next to each other, with one of them having a border